# Gradle Project Sync Failing

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My Project Sync is failing with the below errors -

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not download exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)

My Project build.grade looks like this -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my App gradle file looks like -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
}
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated!!!
How do I resolve this??

I have tried Invalidate Caches/Restart option and also tried to rebuild the project but it didn't help..

Comment: Looking at docs https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer you need to add these:`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'`. Cannot see that in your gradle file. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have added that and tried earlier..it doesn't work

Comment: Gotcha that is facebook audience network lib that needs exoplayer. That’s why you haven’t them explicitly set in your gradle file. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/sdk-dependencies-resolution-on-android

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Exoplayer-core and Exoplayer-dash are broken since today
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5225

Comment: Will try the solutions mentioned in this link and let everyone here know..Ya it seems some issue with bintray..

Answer (score 0):

By this Gradle configuration it works fine :

```
android {
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
  }
}




ext {
    exoplayer_version = '2.9+'
}

dependencies {
    ...

//exoplayer

implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:' + exoplayer_version)
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:' + exoplayer_version)
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:' + exoplayer_version)
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:' + exoplayer_version)
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:' + exoplayer_version)
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:' + exoplayer_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So for sure if you didn't include exoplayer library in your
>   `build.gradle`, your project won't synch.

**UPDATE:**
Okay, sorry, now I got the problem you all using `com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk` have experienced these days, and why in your `build.gradle` file there is not `exoplayer` dependency set.

Using `com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk` that depends on `exoplayer`, if you didn't explicitly specify `exoplayer-core` and `exoplayer-dash`, gradle try to download the necessary dependency as for [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/sdk-dependencies-resolution-on-android).

So, as @laylakn [pointed out](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5225) (upvoted for that) there where an issue between repository mirroring between bintray and jcenter.

So, specifically to your problem, since you have told me that you have tried adding the libraries and synch without success, that's because the version of exoplayer you are looking for (**r2.4.2**) is in the `spring plugin repository`.

[image: spring plugin repo]

So you should add it as your maven repo (because of the mirroring error of repositories stated before):

```
maven {
        url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
      }
```

Or as explain on main GitHub repo, just pointing directly to bintray.

```
maven {
            url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/'
        }
```

and you should synch your project adding this two libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.4'
```

[image]

So now I'm glad to here from you that the mirroring problem has been resolved and are you able to sync right now, without doing any changes to your build.gradle files.

I've left and updated my answer to better explain this situation.

Also some other famous repo take precautions: [-:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @shadowsheep for your inputs. The issue was with jcenter and bintray from last couple of days. Mirroring was not happening from bintray to jcenter and bcuz of which the dependencies were failing. I am able to sync the project now.